# ReactJs: return only unique values from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this returned group of arrays returned as in, which is output console logging an array named `forTypes`:

```
 ["milk", "bread"]
 ["milk"]
 ["bread"]
 ["cheese", "jam"]
```

I have been trying to filter its out using

```
let forTypesUnique = [...new Set(forTypes)];
```

I have also tried using other functions such as `Reduce()` but no luck!

Should I combine those separate arrays into one and then filter out? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: to prevent duplicates you first need to concate all arrays to single one, and only after create a set. you also can use "flat"

Comment: The issue is that the API returns them as such, not even indexed - so I am not sure what to use to access them.

Comment: if you are allowed to use libraries, then use lodash's `flatten` to flatten the nested arrays into a single array of values, which you can then pass to your Set constructor to de-dupe.  If this is some learning exercise where you cannot use libraries, then try looping through the array, then checking if the value you have is also an array, and looping through it...in your loop add items to the set one by one.

Comment: @Zeusox `forTypes` is array of arrays?

Comment: @Brandon I am not allowed to use libraries for that. @ Captain Mhmdrz_A it is not being wrapped into an array or object.

Comment: @Zeusox how do use `...` spread on that then? is it return value of something?

Comment: It looks like I need to wrap everything in an object and then concat that again maybe?

Comment: What do you mean "API returns them as such"? How are they **exactly** returned or what do you see when you do `console.log(response)`, or whatever...? Is it a `string`, `array`, or `object`?

Comment: @Zeusox yeah, they must a have wrapper

Comment: [... new Set([...["milk", "bread"], ...["milk"]])]

Comment: @terpinmd not sure what you mean>

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const forTypes = [
    ["milk", "bread"],
    ["milk"],
    ["bread"],
    ["cheese", "jam"]
];
const flatForTypes = forTypes.flat()
const forTypesUnique = [...new Set(flatForTypes)];

console.log(forTypesUnique)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The issue they do not have a parent array wrapping them up!

Answer (score 1):

Before create set you have to join arrays.

```
const typesGroup = [
    ['milk', 'bread'],
    ['milk'],
    ['bread'],
    ['cheese', 'jam'],
];

const forTypes = [].concat(...typesGroup);
const forTypesUnique = [...new Set(forTypes)];
```

instead of `concat` you can use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) function, but it is in stage 3 proposal for now

```
const forTypes = typesGroup.flat();
```

UPDATED:

if you don't have wrapper array, then you probably have any kind of function which you call to process items, so you can use closure:

```
const setOfTypes = new Set();

...

const updateForTypesList = (forTypes) => {
    forTypes.map(type => setOfTypes.add(type));
    return [...setOfTypes];
}

...

const resultList = updateForTypesList(['milk', 'bread']);
```

Comment: The issue they do not have a parent array wrapping them up!

Answer (score 1):

If all the arrays are come from server as nested array you can do the following:

```
let arr= [
 ["milk", "bread"],
 ["milk"],
 ["bread"],
 ["cheese", "jam"]
]
let f = arr.flat()
console.log(f);// ["milk", "bread", "milk", "bread", "cheese", "jam"]
let result = [...new Set(f)]


console.log(result)// ["milk", "bread", "cheese", "jam"]
```

Comment: The issue they do not have a parent array wrapping them up!

Comment: but may be you can warp them?

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing